# How to activate a solenoid using TSOP4838 IR receiver

Tags: npn, pnp

I have a TSOP4838 whose output is 5v normally and 2.5v when I press a button on my DVD remote. I wish to activate a solenoid when the DVD remote button is pressed. The circuit is is powered by a 9v battery going through a voltage regulator.

I have both NPN and PNP transistors but these TSOP4838 are the only IR components I have at this time.

Comment: What current to drive solenoid, versus what the battery can provide?

Comment: The specs state 12v 1A, but power output from the voltage converter is enough to move it with what I have attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwO30Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

the TSOP4848 pudt out pulsing singal when it seed infrared remote signals, when it goes low it discharges C1, when it goes high or when there is no infrared C1 slowly charges.

when the capacitor is below about 1V Q2 turns off allowing the current through R3  flow into Q1 turing it on. this energises the solenoid and stops the current through R1 this turns Q1 off even harder making sure that the solenoid does not chatter.

Edit:   added D2,C2,R7 to provide a 5v supply to run the TSOP4838 IR receiver
or you can omit those parts and supply 5V to pin 3 by some other means.

Comment: Maybe... but a *practical* setup would usually use an MCU or dedicated decoder to recognize a specific coded pattern

Comment: the question allows only discrete transistors

Comment: Not exactly, the author states that's all they have acquired so far.  It *might* work, but it's not going to be comparable to a real remote system - ie, any button on any remote will work, and some interference sources may too.

Comment: This circuit works but doesn't provide enough power to move the solenoid.

Comment: what voltage do you measure across Q1 with the circuit activated? reducing R3 may help.

Comment: @C.M. Any final working schematic do you have?

Comment: I just edited in an 5v supply to power the TSOP 4838